# Java Framework to interpolate tokens in YAML

Tags: java, yaml, string-interpolation

For Java is there any existing reliable framework that can interpolate tokens in YAML?

My goal is that I would like to part of a YAML to an external file; I may have some XML or JSON embedded in the YAML and I would like to be able to externalize them so that my YAML looks prettier.

Lets say for example I have this YAML template:

```
Root:
  PropertyA: ${valueA}
  PropertyB: | 
     ${valueB}
```

Give that`${valueA}` is `Hello`

And `${valueB}` is:

```
wonderful 
    world
```

I would like the final YAML file to be

```
Root:
  PropertyA: Hello
  PropertyB: |
    wonderful
        world
```

Note that the space in front of the "world" is preserved.

I am more than happy to roll my own code using some YAML parser, but why do that if there are already some open source tool that does it :)

I tried to Google around for this kind of tool but nothing really useful turned up :(

Comment: So all you need to do is go through string line by line and replace ${valueA} with a variable? Seems trivial to do (even in java :p). Am I missing something?

Comment: Doing line by line will not work, especially if the the token is replaced by multi line string because you will likely break the indentation rule of YAML. See my example for "valueB".

Comment: What is valueB supposed to be? Result is not valid yaml, but it is what you asked for. In your question it seems like you want to get invalid yaml. If not, please correct example for valueB. Then my first comment suggestion would work. You also need to detect identation, which is not too hard.

Comment: Also unfortunatelly IME yaml is not pretty when you have object in it which contain other objects. I wouldn't correct that, but accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After closer look at [SnakeYaml](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation); it can actually do what I need. All you need to do is to have a [`Constructor`](http://javadox.com/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/Constructor.html) subclass and override the `constructScalar()` method:

```
Constructor constructor = new Constructor() {
    @Override
    public Object constructScalar(ScalarNode node) {
        if (isToken(node.getValue()) {
            return interpolateToken(node.getValue());
        }

        return super.constructScalar(node);
    }
}

Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
yaml.load(yamlReader);
```